# How to publish to a facebook wall as a different person

Tags: facebook, post, web

I maintain an asp.net website and have a requirement to publish to the businesses facebook wall as the business.

We set up a facebook app to do so.

So what happens is after  a user clicks a button on the website the program calls facebook with scope=publish_stream,offline_access,manage_pages parameter

Facebook returns a code

We call facebook again with something that looks like this

string.Concat("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + facebookPostClientId,
  "&redirect_uri=" + "blah.aspx", "&client_secret=" + facebookPostSecret, "&code=" + code )

Facebook returns an access token.

We then call facebook to get all the accounts with something like this:
https://graph.facebook.com/" + facebook_user_id + "/accounts?access_token=" + accessToken;
We then loop throught the accounts until we find the correct one and call facebook again with something like

https://graph.facebook.com/" + userName + "/feed?&access_token=" + accessToken + "&picture=" + picture + "&name=" + "Studentcard - Deal" + "&link=" + link + "&message=" + message + "&caption=" + caption + "&from=" + userName + "&to=" + userName;

It works after a fashion.  IF the owner of the business who created the facebook app is logged on to facebook, then the processing works.

If anyone else is logged on then it doesn't.

The reason being that the bit where we call facebook to get all th accounts only works when the business owner is logged on to facebook.

I tried inserting the business owners facebook id inbto the code instead off the logged on users, but it doesn't work.

So what do I do? Is this the wrong way to go about this?

I realise this maybe a bit long winded, but I am new to facebook and am providing as much information as I think necessary.

Thanks in advance

Niall

Answer (score 0):

> The reason being that the bit where we call facebook to get all th accounts only works when the business owner is logged on to facebook.

Separate this part of the process. Get all the accounts, and then cache them in your database. Whenever you fail to get the accounts, just use the cached information and proceed normally (otherwise update the DB and proceed normally).